# Use me with excuse

Tags: riddle, word, rhyme, poetry

> Three words; three meanings
>   Below are the clues
>   They overlap to form me
>   Use me with excuse
>
> My prefix is a prefix of
>   being worldwide
>   My infix is a mistake,
>   forgive and set aside
>   My suffix is a suffix of
>   bursting outside
>   For my attention, I disturb you,
>   Who am I to hide?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is it

> **INTERRUPT**?

*My prefix is a prefix of being worldwide*

> being worldwide = 'international' - Prefix '**inter**'

*My infix is a mistake, forgive and set aside*

> **err** is a synonym for mistake

*My suffix is a suffix of bursting outside*

> e**rupt** is a synonym for bursting out

*For my attention, I disturb you*, (and the earlier '*Use me with excuse*')

> When you **interrupt** someone you might say 'excuse me' before disturbing them.

Therefore:

> inter + err + rupt (overlapping) forms **interrupt**

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE and congratulations on your first accepted answer!